# Delay Loop in MIPS

Tags: loops, assembly, count, mips, pic32

I am having trouble writing a delay loop that will return a constant 0x80000. The output should be like Hello, world! 0
Hello, world! 1
Hello, world! 2
...
but when I run my program, the terminal doesn't show anything even though I believe one Hello, world! should be showing up. I tried to figure out what is wrong by debugging the code, but that does not seem to be helping me. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
.ent getDelay
.text
.global getDelay

getDelay:
addi $sp, $sp, -1
sw $ra, 0($sp)
la $a0, helloStr
lw $a1, counter 
jal printf
nop
lw $ra, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, -1
lw $t0, ($a1)
addiu $t0, $t0,1
la $t1, counter
sw $t1, ($a1) 
$v0 = 0x80000
jr $ra

.end getDelay

.data
helloStr: .asciiz "Hello, world %d\n"
counter: .word 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should only ever adjust `$sp` in multiples of 4 (the word size).
   You should use `addiu $sp, $sp, -4` and `addiu $sp, $sp, 4`.
2. You are incrementing `$t0` but then storing `$t1`. You don't need
   the `la $t1, counter` and instead of `sw $t1, ($a1)` you should use
   `sw $t0, ($a1)`.
3. `$v0 = 0x80000` is not an instruction, you probably want `li $v0,
   0x80000`.
4. If this function itself is supposed to be some delay, then you need
   a loop in it.